# setting folder path for rename files

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to rename files on specific folder it works on local system but not on another directory,

this is my code. i hvae my images on this directory I:/Export/*.jpg.  it works on c drive where the batch file is but on I:. when i try this i get this error "the syntax of the command is incorrect."

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.JPG) do ( --                              (I:/exportttt/*.JPG) alos tried this..
set $file="%%a"
set $file="!$file:SYPTE1-PC=BARNSLEY!"
set $file="!$file:SYPTE=BARNSLEY!"
**ren I:\exportttt\ %%a !$file!** I:/exportttt/ -- I also tried this ... 
echo File [%%a] Done)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "I:\exportttt\"
for %%a in (*.JPG) do (                              
    set $file="%%a"
    set $file="!$file:SYPTE1-PC=BARNSLEY!"
    set $file="!$file:SYPTE=BARNSLEY!"
    echo ren %%a !$file! 
    echo File [%%a] Done
)
popd
```